# asp.net mvc2 get the id and value from dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2

I have seen examples of getting the id only or value only but I want to get both from the form post, how is this possible?

current code:

```
<div class="editor-field">
 <%= Html.DropDownList("MySelectedItem", new SelectList(Model.Items, "Value", 
     "Key",Model.Items))%><small class="marker">*</small>
</div>
```

If a user selects item 3 from the drop down I want to get inside the controller:

```
MySelectedItem.Value = 3
MySelectedItem.Key= "something"
```

Comment: It sounds like you should rather work on your code design. The key should be all you needed to identify the value. Why would you need to know the value?

Comment: I know, I messed this up quite bad. I had to ensure I am getting unique values from various tables, the id's (in this case 'value') was clashing.In one table I could find 3 and another table I could find 3, anyway... I think you are right, I am going to prefix my key with something unique and it should work... thanks :)

Comment: And if you do need the value, why don't you just retrieve it again?

Comment: @jeff I could do, but these keys were actaully made up, they could get changed elsewhere. Simply put the design was messed up... I can add a prefix to identify which table it came from and it will be ok.@Qua if you answered I would mark yours as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you should rather work on your code design. The key should be all you needed to identify the value. Why would you need to know the value?

You speak about your value clashing between tables. This should not be an issue either. It sounds like you might want to rework your database design as well. Keys and unique constraints are the only fields in your database that should be unique.

Answer (score 0):

How about just pop of one the values in hidden field on change event using JQuery, easy and simple and you issue solved.

Comment: I did not want to do any client side code, I think @Qua is right, the problem is my design not what I have done client side. If my code design is bad it will make other things harded for me later...

Answer (score 0):

(unless I'm misunderstanding..)

In the browser you'll have something like

```
<select name="MySelectedItem">
    <option value="Model.Item.Value1">Model.Item.Key1</option>
</select>
```

When the form is posted you will have Request.Form["MySelectedItem"] with a value of "Model.Item.Value1" which means you have a couple of choices

1. Populate a hidden field on the client side when the dropdown changes or
2. Reload your collection in the controller and find the item where:

   Item.Value == Request.Form["MySelectedItem"]